# Parse NSDate to String with MM/d/YYY hh:mm aaa format not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having a hard time parsing date strings of type: `3\/3\/2012 12:00:00 AM`. I have the following code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/d/YYYY hh:mm aaa";
    conference.beginDate = [formatter dateFromString:[jsonElement valueForKey:@"BeginDateMember"]];
```

But unfortunately, all of my `beginDate` are `null`.

I am not sure if: a) I need to include the escape backslash in the format, b) I am specifying locale wrong, c) I am specifying format wrong, or d) some combination of the above.

This is a somewhat non-standard date format so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/d/YYYY hh:mm aaa"]; //notice the change here ..
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //.. and here
conference.beginDate = [formatter dateFromString:[jsonElement valueForKey:@"BeginDateMember"]];

[dateFormatter release];
```

If you still get null make sure your jsonElement actually has a value.

Comment: sorry I didn't notice the difference there. Yet, see to it that is has a value. That and use the setLocale/setDateFormat methods.

Answer (score 0):

You format look to be off a bit:

```
formatter.dateFormat = @"MM/d/yyyy hh:mm a";
```

You can find a list of supported formate [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Also if you are not using `ARC` than `autorelease` the `NSLocale`:

```
formatter.locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
```